# What is the use of 'when' in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm triying to use when in Scheme but i dont know why at the last element of my list appears .#void>.

Here is my code

```
(define (genlist x y)
   (when
       (< x y)
       (cons x (genlist (+ x 1) y))))
```

And this is my output =>

```
(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . #void>)
```

Comment: The source of your problems (and the actual reason why it's a code smell to have an `if` without an `else`) is that your code is not handling the case when `(>= x y)`. What should you do in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `when` when we need to write an `if` without an `else` part, and/or when we need to write more than one expression inside the `if`. Only the last expression's value gets returned, hence we use it mostly for the side effects. To understand it better, in Racket this:

```
(when <condition>
  <exp1>
  <exp2>
  <exp3>)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(if <condition>
    (begin
      <exp1>
      <exp2>
      <exp3>)
    (void)) ; implementation-dependent
```

The same considerations apply to `unless`, except that the condition is surrounded with a `(not ...)`.

The source of your problems (and the reason why it's a code smell to have an `if` without an `else`) is that your code is not handling the case when `(>= x y)`. Ask yourself, what should you do in that case? Simple, return an empty list! that's the base case of the recursion that's missing from your code.

Comment: The return value in such case is unspecified in the standard, hence it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: Yes, it's Racket.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use `(if (< x y) (cons ...) '())` to produce a proper list.

`when` (and it's counterpart `unless`) is mostly for doing side effects (like printing something out) in a context where the result is not used.

e.g. `(when debug-mode? (print "got here"))`

Comment: Yes, but when i use if i have the next problem:  if: missing an "else" expression in: (if (< x y) (cons x (generalista (+ x 1) y))). I dont know where the 'else' goes, i tried in all ways.

Comment: the `else` clause is the empty list in the first expression shown by rain1, so it would be a form following your `(cons ... (general... ))` expression

Answer (score 2):

`when` is an one armed ifs with implicit `begin`. The following examples are the same:

```
(if (any odd? lst)
    (begin
      (set! some-binding #t)
      (display "Found an odd element")))


(when (any odd? lst)
  (set! some-binding #t)
  (display "Found an odd element"))
```

And you can use `unless` instead of using `not` in the predicate:

```
(if (not (any odd? lst))
    (set! some-binding #f))

(unless (any odd? lst)
  (set! some-binding #f))
```

Peter Norvig made a nice book about [Lisp style](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/norvig-lisp-style.pdf) and in it he addresses this:

**Be as specific as your data abstractions warrant, but no more.**

- if for two-branch expression
- when, unless for one-branch statement
- and, or for boolean value only
- cond for multi-branch statement or expression

So while you can write all your logic using `if` it will not be the easiest code to read. Other might use the term [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Even though the book is for Common Lisp much of it can be used in Scheme as well. It's a good read if you want to program any lisp dialect professionaly.

For `when` and `unless` this is applies much better to Scheme as you have no idea what an implementation might return in the event the predicate evaluates to `#f` while in CL you could abuse `when` since it's destined to return `nil` in such cases.

In you code you are trying to return something and letting the implementation choose what should happen when the predicate failes is what causes the `#<void>`. When the return matter you should always use two armed `if`:

```
(if test-expression
    then-expression
    else-expression)
```

Note there is no `else` keyword.